# Updating custom user profile

Tags: django, user-profile, django-custom-user

In my web app, I need two users, regular site users and employees. I am using a custom user based on `AbstractUser` to achieve this.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Employee(CustomUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    # other fields
```

In settings.py I have:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.CustomUser'
```

I want to provide a profile page for both the regular site user and the Employee user.

First, I created a form called `UserProfileEditForm` for regular site users:

```
class UserProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserProfileEditForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

the corresponding view:

```
@login_required
def user_profile_edit(request):
    user = get_user_model()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            return redirect('user_profile')
    else:
        form = UserProfileEditForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'user/user_profile_edit.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

and the form:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Update Information</button>
</form>
```

In the edit user profile page, I see the email rightly populated into the email field. When I click submit, I get a validation error message:

> This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.

It is as if the update form is trying to create a new user. What do I do to fix this?

Bonus question: does the same solution work for the user profile page of the Employee user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.exclude(username=username)` from your query in `if` clause inside clean_email method.

As the form class UserProfileEditForm has no username field in it so fetching username from cleandata is useless it will always be None

Also add `self.instance.email != email` to if clause, So current user will able update his profile info.

```
if email and self.instance.email != email and get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).count():
```

**UPDATE 2**

The logged out issue is due to following code inside your `user_profile_edit` method

```
if form.is_valid():
   user = form.save(commit=False)
   # below line of code deactivating user and hence user got logged out, remove these lines 
   user.is_active = False
   user.save()
```

Change above line of code with

```
# You have already mentioned a save method inside UserProfileEditForm class
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
```

Comment: The result is still same with the queryset updated as you mentioned. I get the validation error when I submit.

Comment: Check my update section, try adding one more check over there

Comment: Sorry, adding the clause did not work, I am just being logged out when I submit the data.

Comment: This is strange that you are being logged out on submit. Update `get_user_model() ` code to question, let me try on my local enviroment

Comment: @Animesh logged out issue is due to the code written inside your `user_profile_edit ` view, check my UPDATE 2 section for solution.

Comment: I also update my previous answer, let me know is it now working?, I tried at my local enviroment and it is working for me.

Comment: Satendra, yes I also realized a while ago that `user.is_active` was creating the problem. Is it possible to have it for user creation but bypass it on user update?

Comment: I realized I don't need that and removed it. Thanks for the assistance.